# Build a Docker image remotely using Node.js

Tags: node.js, docker

I want to build a Docker image remotely, by using Node.js. Basically, I've seen that there are projects such as [dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode) and [docker.io](https://github.com/appersonlabs/docker.io) that wrap Docker's remote API, but I'm not sure whether they really are what I am looking for. My basic setup looks like this:

- I have a ready-made image inside of a *private* registry (think Quay.io or something like that). This container has an `ONBUILD` trigger, which basically runs `ADD . /foo/`.
- Now I have a local folder on my notebook I'd like to use as the `.` for the `ONBUILD` command. This folder also container a `Dockerfile`.
- I want the resulting image to be built on a remote machine, without the need to have Docker installed locally.

So basically what needs to be done is to create a small Node.js script that takes the local folder with the `Dockerfile`, and pushes it to a server that runs the Docker server which then in turn is able to fetch the base image from the registry.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Somehow, I'm feeling a little bit lost, because I do not get the right idea where to start. Perhaps, if someone can tell me the steps I need to accomplish, this already would be a great help!

PS: As an additional challenge, I would like to accomplish the same thing *without* having a local `Dockerfile`. It should be created on-the-fly by the Node.js program. Now I wonder whether it is possible to do this without having an additional temporary folder, but somehow keeping it in-memory only?

Comment: Just to clarify one point, Docker client works exactly as you describe: the local directory (called the context) is `tar`ed and pushed to the Docker server as part of the `build` request. I don't know anything about node.js, but as far as I can tell, [you can provide a `tar`ed context to dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode#building-an-image), which seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Sounds good, I didn't know that, but I'm going to have a closer look at this.

Comment: see: https://github.com/Runnable/githubNabber/blob/master/index.js it does pretty much exactly what you describe, except it does it with a streaming incoming tar.  You can use `fstream` to get a local directory into the kind of stream emitter `tar-stream` uses.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! If you turn this into an answer, I will mark it as accepted :-)